# Pass Multiple params in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all, I'm still a beginner in MVC

Obviously anyone knows that we can pass by /CONTROLLER/METHOD/ID, but in some cases, like I need to pass 3-4 params into the controller, how should I do? Is there a good way of passing them all?

The code below is a controller dealing with post request, why I cannot use the "temp1"? it said that one should be declared before use, what that means?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Payment_Home(Wires_SWIFT temp1){
    string str = temp1.BENEFICIARY_NAME;
    DbQuery<Wires_SWIFT> dbq = db.Wires_SWIFT.Where(d => d.BENEFICIARY_NAME LIKE temp1.);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Whether `temp1` contains a value or not depends on the structure of what a `Wires_SWIFT` is and what values are being submitted via the form post from the page.  The names and implicit types of those values should match the properties on a `Wires_SWIFT` object.

Comment: @Oded♦ Made great sense! but is there any way that I can get the string value in temp1? temp1.BENEFICIARY_NAME.ToString() doesn't help

Comment: @LifeScript - It is probably empty - you need to setup the values of post action parameters to have the same names as in the form posting them. This article may be of help: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/the-three-models-of-asp.net-mvc-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have a route set correctly.

so to match `dothis/action/param1/param2` you'd want a route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Surveys", action = "Index", param1 = "param1", param2 = "param2" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

For the above route to actually work, you'll need a controller and action such as

```
public class DoThisController : Controller
....
public ActionResult Action(int param1, int param2)
....
```

The type of the action parameters doesn't matter, but the name should match the name defined in the rule to allow the action to be located by ASP.Net

In your case, the error is because your parameter is called temp1 & in the route data there is nothing called that.

Comment: a very quick question: how can I make it as regular html text between to razor markup tag?
for example:  \@Html.str hello \@Html.str2
How can I make "hello" as html output?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ViewModel`.

This is a class that contains all the values you need - you populate it in the controller action and pass it in to the view (helps if the view is strongly typed to the model.

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string SomeValue { get; set; }
  public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}

// controller
var myModel = new MyModel...
return View(myModel);

// view
@model MyModel

@Model.SomeValue
```

Comment: so how I gonna write my form? Like
@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b)?